# Ruby - Check if intersect exists

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, search, optimization

I'm trying to speed up a search function in a RoR app w/ Postgres DB. I won't explain how it works currently...just go with an /achieve approach!

I have x number of records (potentially a substantial number) which each have an associated array of Facebook ID numbers...potentially up to 5k. I need to search against this with an individual's list of friend IDs to ascertain if an intersect between the search array and any (and which) of the records' arrays exists.

I don't need to know the result of the intersection, just whether it's true or false.

Any bright ideas?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just using pure ruby since you don't mention your datastore:

```
friend_ids = user.friend_ids
results = records.select { |record| !(record.friend_ids & friend_ids).empty? }
```

`results` will contain all records that have at least 1 friend_id in common. This will not be very fast if you have to check a very large number of records.

`&` is the array intersection operator, which is implemented in C, you can see it here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Sorry, im writing this in RoR, though I assumed writing a solution at as low a level as possible would be the most efficient.

Comment: I'm also keen to avoid using the & operator as all I need is a true/false output...if the first value that is checked is present in both arrays, there is no need to continue with the operation.

Comment: At a lower level? What do you mean? If you mean looping though the array in ruby and checking for the first hit, thats going to be slower than array intersect. Here's a benchmark to give you an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436663/data-structures-iterating-over-two-arrays-vs-converting-to-sets-and-performing

Comment: For faster `&`, you might want to grab https://github.com/floere/picky/blob/master/server/lib/picky/ext/ruby19/performant.c

Comment: Thanks! Implemented this morning and the search has been sped up probably around 10 times, so very chuffed. A spot of benchmarking suggested sets would be faster, so I save to DB as a set at the time of creation. Will take a look at this faster &

Comment: @ctcherry a variant on your linked benchmark showing how to use set to get greater speed http://stackoverflow.com/a/10456395/1074296

Answer (score 1):

A probably faster version of @ctcherry's answer, especially when `user.friend_ids` has high cardinality:

```
require 'set'
user_friend_ids = Set[ user.friend_ids ]
results = records.select { |record|
  record.friend_ids.any? { |friend_id| user_friend_ids.include? friend_id }
}
```

Since this constructs the test set(hash) for user.freind_ids only once, it's probably also faster than the [Array#memory_efficient_intersect](https://github.com/floere/picky/blob/master/server/lib/picky/ext/ruby19/performant.c) linked by @Tass.

This may also be faster performed in the db, but without more info on the models, it's hard to compose an approach.